# python repeating countdown timer for discord.Py

Tags: python, datetime, discord.py

I'm trying to make a python bot and as one off the commands i want to dsiplay how long it will be until the server restarts (11pm est) every day.

this is the code i wrote but it gives some weird outputs sometimes, when it's midnight it returns 40 hours until restart.

Can anyone help me out here?

```
@client.command()
async def gettime(self):
    now = datetime.now()
    # 11 est == 17 gmt+1
    reset = datetime.strptime('16:00', '%H:%M')
    if now == reset:
        await self.send('the restart is happening now')
    elif now < reset:
        untilrestarthour = reset.hour - now.hour
        untilrestartminute = 60 - now.minute
        await self.send(f'the restart is happening in {untilrestarthour} hours and {untilrestartminute}''s ')
    elif now > reset:
        untilrestarthour = 24 - (now.hour - reset.hour)
        untilrestartminute = 60 - now.minute
        await self.send(f'the restart is happening in {untilrestarthour} hours and {untilrestartminute} minute''s ')
    else:
        await self.send("error")
```

Comment: maybe use `print(now, reset)` to see what you have in variables

Comment: 2020-05-20 17:02:19.215558
1900-01-01 17:00:00
the reset is happening in 24 hours and 58 minutes

Comment: if you calculate `60 - now.minute` then you have to get these 60 minutes from 24 hours. In current version you substract from `24h+60minutes` which gives 25h

Comment: maybe better set correct date instead of `1900-01-01` and use `now - reset` instead of `now.hour - reset.hour` - it should calculate correctly hours and minutes.

Comment: you could use `reset = now.replace(hour=16, minute=0)` and if it has to be next day then `reset = now.replace(hour=16, minute=0) + timedelta(days=1)` and then `reset - now` gives correct result.

Answer (score 1):

In current version you substract from 24h and from 60minutes so finally you substract from `24h+60minutes` which gives `25h`. You would have to do something like

```
    untilrestarthour = reset.hour - now.hour

    if now.minute > 0:
          untilrestarthour -= 1
          untilrestartminute = 60 - now.minute
    else:
          untilrestartminute = 0
```

But maybe better you should use correct date instead of `1900-01-01` and then you can use `now - reset` or `reset - now` to calculate hours and minutes correctly.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

now = datetime.now()
reset = now.replace(hour=16, minute=0)
#reset += timedelta(days=1) # next day

print('  now:', now)
print('reset:', reset)
print('reset-now:', reset-now)
print('now-reset:', now-reset)

if now == reset:
    print('the restart is happening now')
elif now < reset:
    print('reset in the future:', reset-now)
elif now > reset:
    print('reset in the past:', now-reset)
else:
    print("error")
```

Result

```
  now: 2020-05-20 17:49:04.029570
reset: 2020-05-20 16:00:04.029570

reset-now: -1 day, 22:11:00
now-reset: 1:49:00

reset in the past: 1:49:00
```

The only problem is that `now - reset` (`reset - now`) creates object `datetime.timedelta` which can generate string `1:49:00` but it can't gives separatelly hours 1 and minutes 49. It gives only total seconds and you have to manually conver seconds to hours and minutes

```
print('reset:', reset)
print('  now:', now)

diff = (reset-now)
print('diff:', diff)

seconds = diff.seconds
print('seconds:', seconds)

hours = seconds//3600
seconds = seconds % 3600

minutes = seconds // 60
seconds = seconds % 60

print('hours:', hours, '| minutes:', minutes, '| seconds:', seconds)
```

Result:

```
 reset: 2020-05-21 16:00:37.395018
   now: 2020-05-20 18:00:37.395018

diff: 22:00:00
seconds: 79200
hours: 22 | minutes: 0 | seconds: 0
```